# Javascript getElementById null error

Tags: javascript

I posted quite recently about an issue with javascript in firefox, and it was denoted the problem was likely document.write() overwriting the script somehow. [It was suggested I use IDs to solve the problem of both overwriting the script and to avoid stacking of the information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12028845/1433767).

However, on trying to implement the IDs into my javascript and html code, I found that firebug reports that:

```
"TypeError: document.getElementById("author_container") is null"
```

Despite the fact, that, once again, the ID is already defined under:

```
<p id="author_container"></p>
```

And there are clearly no typos, **and re-arranging the script** into the head section or altering it so the p occurs before the script **makes absolutely no difference**. (Note the other example runs fine despite the script occurring first).

If I use a pre-existing example of an ID and getElementById and run it in firefox, it runs fine:

http://pastebin.com/FTEX1HGE

But if I try to run my code, which doesn't seem that majorly different, I run into issues:
http://pastebin.com/XfGUpZAS

Am I missing something here? How do I alter the code to make it work in firefox? Will firefox allow me to ever run my code correctly? (Find out next week?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your script at the bottom of the page, right before the closing `</body>` tag. In other words, make the script tag the last one of `document.body`. That way the DOM-tree is completely loaded before the scripting starts.

Aside from a number of issues, the real issue is the `document.open` statement in the `GenerateCoord` function. That *clears the complete document*, after which - indeed - no element is left to get by any Id. Here's [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G7QPU/) without it.

Comment: As per the question, (modifying the script position) makes no difference. Not downvoting, but this was denoted in the question.

Comment: Okay, the improved answer helps, I'll remove document.open(). Thank you.